autorest model generation fails when multipart/form-data has string enum
I am trying to generate C# models and client using openapi specification yaml
If I have a property of type enum in multipart/form-data as below :
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                Precedence:
                  type: string
                   enum:
                     - PRIMARY
                     - SECONDARY
                     - COMMON

it throws error :
fatal   | System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at AutoRest.CSharp.Output.Models.RestClientBuilder.BuildRequestBody(IReadOnlyCollection`1 allParameters, BodyMediaType bodyMediaType, OutputLibrary library) in D:\a\_work\1\s\autorest.csharp\src\AutoRest.CSharp\Common\Output\Models\RestClientBuilder.cs:line 285
   at AutoRest.CSharp.Output.Models.RestClientBuilder.BuildRequest(InputOperation operation, IReadOnlyCollection`1 requestParts, Parameter bodyParameter, OutputLibrary library) in D:\a\_work\1\s\autorest.csharp\src\AutoRest.CSharp\Common\Output\Models\RestClientBuilder.cs:line 212
   at AutoRest.CSharp.Output.Models.RestClientBuilder.BuildMethod(InputOperation operation, DataPlaneResponseHeaderGroupType responseHeaderModel) in D:\a\_work\1\s\autorest.csharp\src\AutoRest.CSharp\Common\Output\Models\RestClientBuilder.cs:line 113    
   at AutoRest.CSharp.Output.Models.DataPlaneRestClient.EnsureNormalMethods() in D:\a\_work\1\s\autorest.csharp\src\AutoRest.CSharp\DataPlane\Output\DataPlaneRestClient.cs:line 44
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at AutoRest.CSharp.Output.Models.RestClient.GetOperationMethod(InputOperation request) in D:\a\_work\1\s\autorest.csharp\src\AutoRest.CSharp\Common\Output\Models\RestClient.cs:line 107
   at AutoRest.CSharp.Output.Models.RestClient.BuildAllMethods()+MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\autorest.csharp\src\AutoRest.CSharp\Common\Output\Models\RestClient.cs:line 45
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder1.AddRange(IEnumerable1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at AutoRest.CSharp.Output.Models.RestClient.getMethods() in D:\a\work\1\s\autorest.csharp\src\AutoRest.CSharp\Common\Output\Models\RestClient.cs:line 24
   at AutoRest.CSharp.Generation.Writers.RestClientWriter.WriteClient(CodeWriter writer, DataPlaneRestClient restClient) in D:\a\_work\1\s\autorest.csharp\src\AutoRest.CSharp\Common\Generation\Writers\RestClientWriter.cs:line 32
   at AutoRest.CSharp.AutoRest.Plugins.DataPlaneTarget.Execute(GeneratedCodeWorkspace project, CodeModel codeModel, SourceInputModel sourceInputModel, SchemaUsageProvider schemaUsageProvider) in D:\a\_work\1\s\autorest.csharp\src\AutoRest.CSharp\DataPlane\AutoRest\DataPlaneTarget.cs:line 55
   at AutoRest.CSharp.AutoRest.Plugins.CSharpGen.ExecuteAsync(CodeModel codeModel) in D:\a\_work\1\s\autorest.csharp\src\AutoRest.CSharp\Common\AutoRest\Plugins\CSharpGen.cs:line 38
   at AutoRest.CSharp.AutoRest.Plugins.CSharpGen.Execute(IPluginCommunication autoRest) in D:\a\_work\1\s\autorest.csharp\src\AutoRest.CSharp\Common\AutoRest\Plugins\CSharpGen.cs:line 128
   at AutoRest.CSharp.AutoRest.Plugins.PluginProcessor.Start(IPluginCommunication autoRest) in D:\a\_work\1\s\autorest.csharp\src\AutoRest.CSharp\Common\AutoRest\Plugins\PluginProcessor.cs:line 39
fatal   | Process() cancelled due to failure 

If I remove the enum, it executed successfully,
command : autorest --input-file=swagger.yaml --csharp  --generation1-convenience-client

your enum keyword has invalid indentation.  should be inline with type keyword.
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                Precedence:
                  type: string
                  enum:
                  - PRIMARY
                  - SECONDARY
                  - COMMON


first "type" is name of properties, then within this property I have defined enum
